# how to have a calculated field viewable within a form in real time?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

How do I have a database field that provides a calculation in real time, i.e when the user is entering data into the form?

I tried to run an `afterUpdate` event from the field in the form labeled `Product_Count`:

```
Private Sub Product_Count_AfterUpdate()
    Me.[Total_Price] = Me.[Product Price] * Me.Product_Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that code and let the form do the work by setting the `ControlSource` for the textbox `Total_Price` to:

```
=[Product Price]*[Product_Count]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately this was not the fix as i worked out with my tutor, it would need to save the record first, before being viewable in the form (whilst the form is being used/data entering). Currently, I have it to where a user opens the form, enters some data and i had to implement a button that would run the calculations and save them, so the user can see the calculation displayed, whilst still having the form open.

Comment: It _is_ the answer, you are looking for. Tell your tutor, that he record doesn't need to be saved, only the textbox, you are modifying (bound to [Product Price] or [Product_Count]), which will happen as soon as you exit that textbox. Neither is a button is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Control Source of a TextBox to the expression: `=[Product Price] * Product_Count`. The TextBox will update automatically when one of the other two TextBoxes is edited.

Comment: Same as comment above, but thank you so much.